# WebGL Constructive Solid Geometry to Static Vertices

Tags: webgl

I'm super new to 3D graphics (I've been trying to learn actual WebGL instead of using a framework) and I'm now in the constructive solid geometry phase. I know sites like tinkercad.com use CSG with WebGL, but they have things set so that your design is calculated every time you load the page instead of doing the subtraction, addition and intersection of primitive objects once and then storing those end design vertices for later use. I'm curious if anybody knows why they're doing things that way (maybe just to conserve resources on the server?) and if there isn't some straightforward way of extracting those vertices right before the draw call? Maybe a built in function of WebGL? Haven't found anything so far, when I try logging the object data from gl.bufferData() I'm getting multiple Float32Arrays (one for each object that was unionized together) instead of one complete set of vertices.

By the way, the only github I've found with CSG for WebGL is this https://github.com/evanw/csg.js/ and it's pretty straightforward, however it uses a framework and was curious if you know of any other CSG WebGL code out there that doesn't rely on a framework. I'd like to write it myself either way, but just being able to see what others have done would be nice.

Comment: I dont know much about CSG but if all you want is to extract the vertices used for the draw call, that should be pretty straight forward with a webGL inspector. (Or inject gl.bufferData with your own version that logs the vertices passed in and call then the real gl.bufferData)

Comment: Just tried it, with the example I'm using, there are 5 objects being combined into one... when I use a console.log on the data being passed to the buffer, I'm getting 5 objects... not one final object... I'll update my question with this comment

Comment: Could you check with say, 10 objects and see how many times gl.bufferData is called? Its likely that the program uses multiple VBOs (like one for vertices, one for color, one for indices and so on)

Comment: Well that's a bizarre coincidence lol, you're right, I still only get 5 objects...  any recommendations on learning resources?